# Replace specific section of string text when string length is dynamic

Tags: sql

I am trying to work on a string manipulation using sql that changes the text after 'str[' (having already go the string from a table using a dbo.function).

The original string looks like this:

`2.2.2.3[1.2.3] - 4.3.2.1 - t+ 3 - kb - str[8.6.5.4.3]`

and the result this :

`2.2.2.3[1.2.3] - 4.3.2.1 - t+ 3 - kb - str[10.8.6.5.4]`

The string can often be larger or smaller in length of characters before 'str[' and because there are brackets throughout the string, I can't use these as something to hold onto. Just wondering if anyone has some suggestions.

Comment: Please tag appropriate database name. And please confirm the expected replace pare is always the last part of the string or not?

Comment: It will always be the last part of the string. In terms of database it SQL Server I think, but the MSSQL works well for this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following script written considering SQL Server but you can apply the same logic for other databases with changed syntax-

**Note:** This will only work considering your target string is the last part of your source string and the new string is fixed 'str[10.8.6.5.4]'

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX) = '2.2.2.3[1.2.3] - 4.3.2.1 - t+ 3 - kb - str[8.6.5.4.3]'

SELECT LEFT (@S, CHARINDEX('str[', @S,0) - 1) + 'str[10.8.6.5.4]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, the following query containing `reverse()`, `charindex()`, `replace()`, `substring()` and `parsename()` might be used together :

```
with t(str0) as
(
 select '2.2.2.3[1.2.3] - 4.3.2.1 - t+ 3 - kb - str[8.6.5.4.3]'
), t2 as
(
 select reverse(substring(reverse(str0),2,charindex('[',reverse(str0))-2)) as str,
        str0
   from t
)
select replace( str0, str,
       concat(
       '10.',  
       substring(str,1,charindex('.',str)-1),'.',
       parsename(substring(str,charindex('.',str)+1,len(str)),4),'.',
       parsename(substring(str,charindex('.',str)+1,len(str)),3),'.',
       parsename(substring(str,charindex('.',str)+1,len(str)),2)) ) as Result
  from t2;
```

where the number of dots are assumed to be fixed to be able to use `parsename()`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ed360b390769323c8f383e0e8376a108)</kbd>